# Pictures in the slideshow aren't showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

Only the first three photos in my site's slideshow are showing... I don't know how to fix it, I'm not really sure what the problem is since it was working fine few weeks ago but it suddenly stopped working, I don't know what I have done wrong though.

http://whybaguio.com/ - that's the site.

Thanks ! :)

Comment: I can see all 5 fine if I click the dots at bottom.  When the cycle goes it cycles the first 3 then starts over.  Looks like a javascript problem to me.  Not a javascript expert tho so I'll leave it to the professionals.

Comment: you are getting a 404 on the images...did you check that?

Comment: @theshadowmonkey really? but when I click the dots , it shows the remaining two pictures....

Comment: @Michael Yes, yes -that's what I really need help of :)) thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `button3_click()` and `button4_click()`, you are setting the timeout to `button1_click()`. This is why it's going back to the first picture after the third picture is shown. Just change the timeouts to the correct function and it will work as expected.

```
function button3_click(event)
{
...
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(eval("button4_click"),"3000");
...
}

function button4_click(event)
{
...
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(eval("button5_click"),"3000");
...
}
```